# Python local variable referenced before as assignment

Tags: python

So basically i defined the variable before (globally)
However, it still says variable referenced before assignment.

I am a beginner and i dont know how to use this so please forgive me if i am doing something wrong

```
import time
import multiprocessing
i = True
upgrade_level = 0
money = 10

def clear_chat():
  num = 0
  while num < 100:
    print(" ")
    num += 1




def loop1():
  while i:
    question = input("Would you like to upgrade? (y)\n")
    if(question.lower() == "y"):
      if(money >= 10):
        clear_chat()
        money = money-10
        print("You upgraded once")
        print("Your upgrade level is " + str(upgrade_level))
      elif(money < 10):
        clear_chat()
        print("You do not have enough money ($10) to buy an upgrade")
    else:
      clear_chat()
      print("You can only input (y)")
  
def loop2():
  while i:
    money += 10
    time.wait(10)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop1())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop2())
```

Comment: You might want to put something like `global money` in each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `time.wait()` is accully `time.sleep()`.

The main problem in your code is, you haven't added the `global` keyword in function. you can read the global variable without `global` keyword, but in order to make changes in it you have to use `global` keyword, i.e use `global money` in both loops.

Instead of `clear_chat()` functions, you can use the following:

```
if os.name == 'posix':
    os.system('clear') # for MAC os and linux
else:
 
    os.system('cls') # for windows platform
```

To clear the python screen or Console.

Comment: Btw, loop 2 doesnt work, do u know how to fix this? (money not increasing).

Comment: @Backdoor , that's because you are using 2 infinite loop one with `money-=10` and `money+=10` both increases and decreases in same amount, so if you give input as `y` then money won't increase other wise it would.

Comment: Uh it was becuase wrong syntax for multiprocessing

Comment: Also, the first infinite loop stops until you input something i guess?

Comment: Btw, i get EOF error while reading line (quesiton = input("would you like to upgrade (y)"))

Comment: @Backdoor , yes loop stops until we input something, and here is a link that might [help](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/amp/)

Comment: I would also like to advice you to first look up for the error in Google, and if nothing solves your problem, then you are free to ask here at stack overflow, and ** you can use `try except ` to prevent python to close if any error appears.**

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import multiprocessing
i = True
upgrade_level = 0
money = 10

def clear_chat():
  num = 0
  while num < 100:
    print(" ")
    num += 1




def loop1():
  global money
  while i:
    question = input("Would you like to upgrade? (y)\n")
    if(question.lower() == "y"):
      if(money >= 10):
        clear_chat()
        money = money-10
        print("You upgraded once")
        print("Your upgrade level is " + str(upgrade_level))
      elif(money < 10):
        clear_chat()
        print("You do not have enough money ($10) to buy an upgrade")
    else:
      clear_chat()
      print("You can only input (y)")
  
def loop2():
  global money
  while i:
    money += 10
    time.wait(10)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop1())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop2())
```

I included global keyword below loop1 func declaration

Comment: second loop i.e `loop2` will also use `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the global keyword in each function where you want to use it to access it like this,

```
import time
import multiprocessing
i = True
upgrade_level = 0
money = 10

def clear_chat():
  num = 0
  while num < 100:
    print(" ")
    num += 1




def loop1():
  global money
  while i:
    question = input("Would you like to upgrade? (y)\n")
    if(question.lower() == "y"):
      if(money >= 10):
        clear_chat()
        money = money-10
        print("You upgraded once")
        print("Your upgrade level is " + str(upgrade_level))
      elif(money < 10):
        clear_chat()
        print("You do not have enough money ($10) to buy an upgrade")
    else:
      clear_chat()
      print("You can only input (y)")
  
def loop2():
  global money
  while i:
    money += 10
    time.wait(10)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop1())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop2())
```

Can read this for examples https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the variable 'money' in both functions is the global one you initialized beforehand using the keyword global. Like this:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
i = True
upgrade_level = 0
money = 10

def clear_chat():
  num = 0
  while num < 100:
    print(" ")
    num += 1

def loop1():
  global money
  while i:
    question = input("Would you like to upgrade? (y)\n")
    if(question.lower() == "y"):
      if(money >= 10):
        clear_chat()
        money = money-10
        print("You upgraded once")
        print("Your upgrade level is " + str(upgrade_level))
      elif(money < 10):
        clear_chat()
        print("You do not have enough money ($10) to buy an upgrade")
    else:
      clear_chat()
      print("You can only input (y)")
  
def loop2():
  global money
  while i:
    money += 10
    time.wait(10)

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop1())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = loop2())
```

However, note that the i variable is never changed to False and that creates an infinite loop.
Check this article for more info on the error: [Article](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment/#:%7E:text=The%20local%20variable%20referenced%20before,assignment%20within%20a%20function%27s%20body.&text=As%20the%20global%20variables%20have,global%20variable%20within%20a%20function.)